# matlab: GUI, custom legend

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axes

On one chart I have several line plots, and one dot plot, something like that:

```
for i = 1:10
    plot(x_1(i, :), y_1(i, :), '-k');
end

plot(x_2, y_2, '.r')'
```

Now I want to have a simple, 2 elements legend showing description of line (only one, not all) and dots. How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use handles:

```
for i = 1:10
    h_line(i) = plot(x_1(i, :), y_1(i, :), '-k');
end

h_dots = plot(x_2, y_2, '.r');

legend([h_line(1) h_dots],{'line','dots'})
```